# Java Map String BigDecimal get function

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, get, bigdecimal

```
public Set<Product> getProductsBypriceFilter(Map<String, BigDecimal> filterParams) {
    Set<Product> productsByPrice = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> criterias = filterParams.keySet();


    if (criterias.contains("low")) {
        for (Product product : listOfProducts) {
            if (product.getUnitPrice().compareTo(filterParams.get("low"))>=0  ) {
                productsByPrice.add(product);
            }
        }
    }
    return productsByPrice ;
}
```

I want to compare product price with "low" price from `Map` but I get error

> java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal

Is `filterParams.get("low")` a `linkedlist` of one value? I can't access it like List.

Comment: What's the definition of product.getUnitPrice() ?

Comment: public BigDecimal getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

Comment: Is it your 'compareTo' line that throw that error ?

Comment: whats the o/p while printing the value of `filterParams`.

Comment: I can run it without it properly
System.out.println(">>>"+filterParams.get("low")) I get output for example >>>[400]

Answer (score 0):

Your `product.getUnitPrice()` method seems to be returning a `LinkedList` object instead of a `BigDecimal` one. Since you did not supply the code for `Product.getUnitPrice()` it is hard to help you any further.